# SugarCRM :create custom Module for sugarc CE 6.5.2

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using **sugar6.5.2** want to develop **User Hierarchy** module.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution for User Hierarchy Module For SugarCRM 6.5.* please visite this site and fallow the steps http://amolbansode.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/user-hierarchy-module-for-sugar-crm-6-5/

I have implemented successfully User Hierarchy Module might also helpful  for some else..

Answer (score 0):

With SugarCRM you can build pretty much anything you'd like. The biggest question is always the balance between time/cost vs  benefit. I'm unsure what the question is in your case but it would definitely be possible. Others have already built User Hierarchy type modules. You may want to look at those first. For example: http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/zuckerh/ and http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/useraccess/

Best of luck!

Comment: Yes But For SugarCRM CE 6.5.2 NO module is available. ZuckerHierarchy we installation problem

Comment: See my answer to your original question. It still answers the very vague non-question.